# Which is a good book to read about history of Buddhism?

Tags: history, books, early-buddhism

I'd like to read about the history of Buddhism. Which book or books would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Buddhism: Its History and Literature, by T.W. Rhys Davids
- Buddhist India, by T.W. Rhys Davids
- Early Buddhist Monachism (600 B.C. - 100 B.C.), by Sukumar Dutt
- History of Buddhism in Ceylon: The Anurādhapura Period, 3rd Century BC – 10th Century AC, by Walpola Rahula
- History of Indian Buddhism: From the Origins to the Śaka Era, by Étienne Lamotte
- The Buddhist Religion: A Historical Introduction, by Richard H. Robinson
- The History of Buddhist Thought, by Edward J. Thomas
- Theravada Buddhism: A Social History from Ancient Benares to Modern Colombo: (Second Edition), by Richard F. Gombrich
- Indian Buddhism (A.K Warder),
- History of Indian Buddhism (Hirakawa Akira),
- How Buddhism Began (Gombrich).
- The Birth of Insight (Erik Braun).
- The Origin of Buddhist Meditation (Alexander Wynne),
- Buddha and Buddhist Synods in India and Abroad (Amarnath Thakur).
- Bones, Stones, and Buddhist Monks: Collected Papers on the Archaeology, Epigraphy, and Texts of Monastic Buddhism in India (Gregory Schopen).

There is a more of such books at http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/

Comment: I also suggest: Indian Buddhism (A.K Warder), History of Indian Buddhism (Hirakawa Akira), How Buddhism Began (Gombrich). Later history: The Birth of Insight (Erik Braun). Specific topics: The Origin of Buddhist Meditation (Alexander Wynne), Buddha and Buddhist Synods in India and Abroad (Amarnath Thakur). More on the archeology side: Bones, Stones, and Buddhist Monks: Collected Papers on the Archaeology, Epigraphy, and Texts of Monastic Buddhism in India (Gregory Schopen).